# what is the best php library to parse RSS feeds?

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed

I am trying to parse iTunes top movies (top songs, albums etc) RSS feed, using PHP.  Is there a library that I can use to parse them, without writing too much XML code (or using simplexml)?  I tried [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/), but it gave me some inconsistent results, and it is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good overview: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/php-rss-parsers/

Comment: thank you.  Zend seems pretty good, other libraries don't seem to be maintained that actively.  Do I need to download the entire zend framework to use the zend_feed library?

Comment: I believe you do - it's not too large though.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, that is why you should have copied the answer here and not just pasted a link.

Answer (score 1):

[SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) is actually maintained and very useful. Open a bug report if you experience inconsistencies.